# How would one say something like "It drives as fast as it looks"?

Tags: grammar

I was looking up the ways one can use みたいに when the thought came to me. I've seen a couple ways, but I want to be sure about this, so I can about how to write more complex comparisons

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about using みたいに in a sentence that expresses what you are trying to say, but my suggestion would be:

> あの車は見た目と同じくらい速い

Comment: Or 見た目通り速い, 見た目の通り速い.